# Растянуть фон по вертикали и горизонтали на всю ширину блока CSS

Tags: html, css

В документации сказано, что `background-size:cover`растягивает изображение так, чтобы оно по высоте и(или) по ширине было растянуто по всему блоку, но картинка растягивается только по ширине (в качестве фона использую картинку 1200x700).

Если сделать экран очень маленьким в ширину, то виден пробел между фоном и концом блока.

Можно ли как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы фон пропорционально растягивался и по ширине и по высоте.

Я предполагаю, что изображение должно увеличиваться, если ему не хватает расстояния до одной из сторон.

Comment: Там, наверное, вначале сообщения должно быть `background-size: cover;`

Comment: Проверьте reset css. Возможно проблема в обнулении отступов и рамки

Answer (score 4):

```
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

**Очевидно же, первое число по ширине, второе по высоте:** https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Если же мы напишем вот так `background-size: 100%;` то это интерпритируется как     `background-size: 100% auto;` то есть высота будет выравниваться пропорционально, **а нам это не нужно, по этому нужно явно указать что высота должна быть не авто а 100% от высоты блока.** Изи катка

Answer (score 2):

Без воспроизводимого примера в вопросе сложно предположить в чем именно проблема. Вам подойдет именно `background-size: cover;`, он возможно не срабатывает по нескольким причинам. Например, само изображение фона содержит белые полосы, откройте изображение и посмотрите есть ли они там. Например, возможно, изображение не отцентрировано. Например, возможно другие стили перекрывают ваши, посмотрите в инспекторе. Или возможно сам блок, на который вы добавляете фон не на всю высоту или ширину нужного блока. Вот небольшой наглядный пример с фонами, возможно вам поможет:

```css
span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px;
  color: #2d5857;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 20px;
  background: white;
  margin: 6px;
}

div {
  color: white;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXyZl.jpg);
  border: 6px solid yellow;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

.bg_1 {
  background-position: center;
}

.bg_2 {
  background-size: cover;
}

.bg_3 {
  background-size: contain;
}

.bg_4 {
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg_5 {
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

.bg_6 {
  background-position: bottom 10px right 40px;
  background-size: 60px 120px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>no styles</span>
</div>
<div class="bg_1">
  <span>
background-position: center;
</span>
</div>
<div class="bg_2">
  <span>
  background-size: cover;
  </span>
</div>
<div class="bg_3">
  <span>
  background-size: contain;
  </span>
</div>
<div class="bg_4">
  <span>
  background-size: cover;
  <br>background-position: center;
  </span>
</div>
<div class="bg_5">
  <span>
  background-size: contain;
  <br>background-repeat: no-repeat;
  <br>background-position: center;
  </span>
</div>
<div class="bg_6">
  <span>
  background-position: bottom 10px right 40px;
  <br>background-size: 60px 120px;
  <br>background-repeat: no-repeat;
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте contain для свойства background-size:

```
background-size: contain;
```

Comment: Оно не подойдёт, т.к это свойство просто вклинит картинку в блок, тогда пробелы будут 100%

Comment: А вот и нет https://jsfiddle.net/85ewq9nL/1/ , пробелов как-раз не будет)

Comment: действительно она растянута как нужно, но вот я делаю свое изображение с эффектом parallax, примерно как тут http://goldneedle.by/ , там главное изображение (tittle) тоже имеет cover и тому подобное, но вот, если вы уменьшите окно(в высоту тоже) вы увидете как картинка становится не на всю ширину контейнера, может быть вы знаете, с чем это связано?

Comment: Я понял причину, если картинка cover с attachment fixed, то она не будет растягиваться на весь блок, а только на весь экран..., это очень плохо, и мне нужно это как-то исправить

Comment: @simplygood Дак вы определитесь - вам нужно чтобы изображение было на весь блок или паралакс? Суть паралакса в том, что фоновое изображение слегка перемещается когда двигаешь мышкой. А чтобы оно перемещалось и не появлялось белых полос - изображение должно быть несколько больше самого блока. Поэтому для паралакса нужно `background-size` вычислять так чтобы высота (или ширина, что меньше) были 110% (вторая ось - высчитывать сколько по соотношению в %), `background-position: 50% 50%`, а уже при движении мышкой вычислять смещение и "играться" с `background-position`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте

background-size: cover;

Comment: Написано же что не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.block {
margin: 5px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQoD4.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.block_one {
  background-size: auto;
}

.block_two {
  background-size: cover;
}

.block_three {
  background-size: contain;
}
.block_for {
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
background-size: auto;
<div class="block block_one"></div>
background-size: cover;
<div class="block block_two"></div>
background-size: contain;
<div class="block block_three"></div>
background-size: 100% 100%;
<div class="block block_for"></div>
```